# "Migrating" existing Git repository to Gerrit Code Revision

Tags: git, gerrit

We have a git repository that we have been working on and committing to during the past year.

We chose to introduce Gerrit Review into our project.

I understand that Gerrit seamlessly works with Git and I think I know how to be able to switch over through Gerrit.

However, my question here is:

**Is it possible to pick randomly selected commits (on an almost linear tree) and play them through Gerrit Review pretending as if they were new commits, submitted for review and merge them on approval?**

*I realize it doesnt make sense to review already committed code...it is still something that has to be done  :(*

Thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and checkout a new branch on an old commit, then do

```
git commit --amend
```

and add the change id to the commit message. This will create a *new* commit with the same content as the original one on the repository because git *never* changes and existing commit.

Now if you push that branch to gerrit, you can start a new review.

Comment: Wow! +1 I did not think of `amend` option. Thanks for your answer! I will try it and mark your answer accordingly...